# Git character encoding with Spanish characters

Tags: git, encoding, filenames, character

I created a repository from existing files. Inside the set of files, was one with the name "español.gif". Now, everytime I do

```
$ git status
```

I receive an error:

```
$ path/espa�ol.gif: Protocol error
```

I tried removing the files using

```
$ git rm path/espa�ol.gif
$ git rm --cached path/espa�ol.gif
$ git rm path/espa?ol.gif
$ git rm --cached path/espa?ol.gif
```

but, nothing changes, it keeps saying "Protocol error".

If I try a merge, I receive:

> error: Your local changes to 'path/espa�ol.gif' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.

Is there any way to remove the file from the index, and stop having this error?

Edit: I solved the problem deleting the Git repository and creating it again, without any file with an Spanish character in the name.

Comment: It's just **mind-boggling to me** that in this day and age, **well into the 21st century**, there's **still** software brain-dead enough that it can't even support 8-bit Western European character sets - not to mention UTF-8 ..... I have the same issues with German umlauts (ä ö ü and so forth) - but still no solution other than falling back to old 7-bit ASCII names - like in the 1970's or so......

Comment: @marc_s, git suports them just fine. Including the "español.gif". Judging by what the OP posted, the file isn't named "español.gif" but something invalid (incorrectly encoded).

Comment: If the file is named español.gif, why do you try to delete espa�ol.gif?

Comment: @marc_s, I just created a repo with files "español.gif" and "ä ö ü" in it. No issue whatsoever.

Comment: Sounds like your shell/terminal is not configured properly.

Comment: @ikegami: can you try using something like "Kündigungsbestätigung.sql" or something like that??

Comment: The original file was "español.gif", when i create the repository from the existing files, git "renames" it "espa�ol.gif"

Comment: @marc_s, Just did. No problem. Edit: Not on Windows at the moment.

Comment: @Alejandro Fiore, Are you on Windows?

Comment: Try to remove the file from Netbeans in Windows 7, and same problem, nothing change.

Comment: Use some functionality from Netbeans, and some other form an OpenSuse Virtual Machine (with a shared folder)

Comment: @Alejandro Fiore, Are you on Windows?

Comment: Sorry, use some functionality from Netbeans in Windows 7 64 bits, and some other from an OpenSuse Virtual Machine (with a shared folder) running in VirtualBox. I don´t use msysgit.

Comment: This should have been a comment to the original question, as it does nothing to solve the problem described in the question. With 11K+ rep, you should know that already.

Comment: @Ken White, Pointing out he's not using the right file name is not a possible solution?!?

Comment: @Alejandro Fiore, You keep bringing up NetBeans (about which I know nothing), but your said your problem is with `git`. I don't understand the relation between the two. Are you saying you are using `git` in an OpenSuse virtual box, and that the repo is on a Windows file system accessed through a share? I'm going to think about it.

Comment: If the file name contains an invalid UTF8 sequence, try removing espa*ol.gif -- the sequence might be represented by more than a single character / byte.

Comment: what is the locale you are using?

Comment: I tried removing espa*ol.gif, but nothing change.

Comment: For what it's worth, the file name isn't showing up consistently in my browser (Firefox 6.0, Windows XP).  The `ñ` character is being displayed as a white question mark inside a black diamond (`espa�ol`).  The page encoding is UTF-8.  The correct UTF-8 encoding for `ñ` is 0xC3, 0xB1; the encoding in your question is 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD.  Perhaps something is being encoded twice?  This might be relevant if you copy-and-pasted the name into your question.  (But that doesn't explain why removing `espa*ol.gif` didn't work.)

Answer (score 15):

This should solve the problem

```
git config core.quotepath false
```

From [man git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for core.quotepath:

> The commands that output paths (e.g.  ls-files, diff), when not
>   given the -z option, will quote “unusual” characters in the
>   pathname by enclosing the pathname in a double-quote pair and with
>   backslashes the same way strings in C source code are quoted. If
>   this variable is set to false, the bytes higher than 0×80 are not
>   quoted but output as verbatim. Note that double quote, backslash
>   and control characters are always quoted without -z regardless of
>   the setting of this variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `git clean` (probably `git clean -d -f` but **consult git manual first**!) command to remove *untracked files* - this is the reason for error message "error: Your local changes ....".

Because of the encoding problems, Git probably already created a file with a bad filename and although the whole (pull/push?) operation was rejected, the already created file remained in the destination.

Comment: BEWARE! Although useful, "git clean" command is particulary destructive (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean). Make sure you HAVE non-git backups before using this command because every untracked file/folder will be erased from your local project. Using -i switch (interactive mode) provides you a proper sense of what is happening. Cheers!